# PostgreSQL Can't multiply inside code blocks

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

```
do $$
declare
    b integer = 5;
begin
    set b to 2 * 50;
end;
$$
```

The star character throws a syntax error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "*"
LINE 30:  set b to 2 * 50;
                     ^
```

I'm bewildered. Is it confusing the star with a star from a select statement?

Comment: `SET … TO …` doesn't do what you think it does. If you want an assignment, just write `b := 2 * 50;` in PL/PGSQL.

Comment: Postgres  does not use *set* for assignment (except in `update`) neither does it use *to* in assignment.  Your statement simply be `b = 2 *  50`. Not that you will know the result a `do` block cannot take parameters not does it produce output other than response to DML.

Answer (score 2):

[`SET … TO …`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-set.html) doesn't do what you think it does. If you want an [assignment in PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT), just write

```
b = 2 * 50;
```

or

```
b := 2 * 50;
```